# Oracle : How to grant to a ROLE the ability to grant a ROLE to a USER?

Tags: oracle

I have a role : `ADMIN_ROLE`

I'm connected as `ADMIN_ROLE` and created a `TEST_USER` and `TEST_ROLE`

I would like to be able to grant `TEST_ROLE` to `TEST_USER` using `ADMIN_ROLE`

I did (using system user) :

```
Grant create role to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
Grant create user to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
```

but when executing from `ADMIN_ROLE` :

```
Grant TEST_ROLE to TEST_USER
```

I'm receiving error:

> ORA 1932 - ADMIN option not granted for role string.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me on 11.2:

```
CONN SYSTEM/<>
CREATE ROLE admin_role;
Grant create role to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
Grant create user to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
CREATE USER john IDENTIFIED BY john;
Grant admin_ROLE to john;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO john;
CREATE USER john2 IDENTIFIED BY john2;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO john2;

CONN john/john
CREATE ROLE test_role;
grant test_role TO john2;

DROP ROLE ADMIN_ROLE;
DROP ROLE TEST_ROLE;
DROP USER john CASCADE;
DROP USER john2 CASCADE;
```

Grant, executed in 10 ms

Try redoing it, you probably missed an admin option when you tried for the first time.
Drop everything.